# How to use XSLT to get a row value in a table

Tags: xslt

I need help in using xslt to retrieve a row value from a table using another row value.

I have a table as follows:

```
Employee       Manager
ABC           PQR
ABC           LMN
DEF           XYZ
IJK           XYZ
```

Employee can belong to more than one department and can have more than one manager.

and the xml for the table is:

```
<List>
    <Mapping>
      <Employee>ABC</Employee>
      <Manager>PQR</Manager>
  </Mapping>
  <Mapping>
      <Employee>ABC</Employee>
      <Manager>LMN</Manager>
  </Mapping>
  <Mapping>
      <Employee>DEF</Employee>
      <Manager>XYZ</Manager>
  </Mapping>
  ...
</List>
```

I get the employee name from a function. Using employee name as input in XSLT, how should i find the employee's manager name using XSLT. My only output value should be the Manager Name either a list or single value. Passing "ABC" employee name should give me both "PQR" and "LMN" as manager values.

Thanks
KSR81

Comment: Can you show the desired XML output for this sample input?

Comment: Sounds like he wants text output, not XML.

Comment: @Jim, @Larsh: Yes i need text output. I will get emp name from a function. string emp = getEmployeeName(); i should pass emp to the xslt and get the desired manager name. how should i do using xslt?

Comment: Whether it's XML or text, please show exactly what output you want. E.g. does `should give me both "PQR" and "LMN"` mean that you want them quoted? separated by spaces?

Comment: I don't think XSLT is going to be more useful than a simple XPath expression for your host language...

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:param name="empName" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Mapping[Employee = $empName]">
        <xsl:value-of select="Manager"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This will output the name of each manager for the given employee, separated and terminated by a space.

To do this more efficiently, you will probably want to use [keys](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key):

```
<xsl:param name="empName" />

<xsl:key name="mappingByEmployee" match="Mapping" use="Employee" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('mappingByEmployee', $empName)">
        <xsl:value-of select="Manager"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <xsl:for-each select="Mapping">
     <xsl:if test="Employee = "ABC"">
         <xsl:value-of select="manager"/>
     <xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Check here for [more](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/xsl_if.asp), and working with parameters [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321704)?

Comment: thanks alliswell. but the employee name would not be always ABC. i will get the employee name from a function. <p> Eg: string emp = getEmpName(); <p> And i should pass emp variable to the xslt and get the respective manager values.

Comment: Ok, than you need to pass XSLT parameter, are you using C#?